# WordPress page-container padding

Tags: html, css, wordpress, padding

I am unable to remove padding gap at the top of my page just below the navbar in a Wordpress theme (divi). I think I've identified the possible culprit as being the page-container div, which has a top padding of 78px. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xONAQ.jpg

50px seems to remove it when tinkering within the browser preview, but it won't carry over when I make the change and reload the page. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc7Jl.jpg

I've tried about 10 different CSS overrides within the theme, but nothing seems to remove it. Does anyone have a possible suggestion? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `padding-top: 78px` style has been added inline which is why it overwrites the `padding-top` which you add inside your stylesheet. You will need to use `!important` here. You can add this CSS at the bottom of your stylesheet and this should work:

```
.et_fixed_nav #page-container {
     padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Fixed. Thank you, Fahad!